# Why doesn't Picard-Lindelof theorem apply here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the IVP $\frac{du}{dt} = f(u,t) = 100cos(ut)$ with $u(0) = u_0$ on the interval $[0,55]$, the question is whether this is guaranteed to have a unique solution. Below is my proof that it does:[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr0E6.png)

> b) Let $f(u, t)=100 \cos (u t)$ on $[0,55]$.
>
> For $x_{1}<x_{2}$ mean value theorem tells us $\frac{\cos (x_{2})-\cos (x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}=-\sin (x^{\star})$ for some $x^{\star} \in(x_{1}, x_{2})$. Thus we
> know that $\left|\frac{\cos (x_{2})-\cos (x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\right| \leq 1$ for any choice of $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R} .$ Now let $x_{1}=u_{1} t$ and $x_{2}=u_{2} t$ so that
> on the interval $t \in[0,55]$ we have $\left|100 \cos (u_{2} t)-100 \cos (u_{1} t)\right| \leq 100 t\left|u_{2}-u_{1}\right| \leq 5500\left|u_{2}-u_{1}\right|$.
> So $f(u, t)$ is Lipschitz on $[0,55]$, meaning it has a unique solution there.

However after plotting in graph, it seems like trajectories are intersecting and things are not quite right. Can someone explain why Picard's theorem does not apply?

Comment: What’s the diff eq?

Comment: edited to clarify!

Comment: Trajectories can intersect as the equation is non autonomous right?

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this fact. And I assume it does not affect uniqueness?

Comment: yup! (didn't get a notification somehow)

Comment: If $f$ has continuous partials in some neighborhood around the given point, the there is a unique solution. Cauchy's theorem if memory serves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions are unique. This is not a contradiction with the intersecting trajectories because your equation is not autonomous!

I wanted to add: non-uniqueness would be hard to detect by numerics; they tend to be unstable. For instance $y'=\sqrt y$ is not Lipschitz so fails the hypothesis of P-L theorem. And it indeed has infinitely many different solutions with $y(0)=0$: one is $y\equiv 0$, one more coming from solving the separable ODE, and a whole family of solutions that start out as $y\equiv 0$ but then at an arbitrary time $t_0$ switch to the other solution. The numerical issue is that if you have $y(0)>0$ but super super tiny, you should see the solution immediately separate from $y\equiv0$.